# Why do we pass the reference arg into the function creating the list_head_insert function in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

Here are some codes for creating a Linked list by inserting the elements in the head.But I don't know why we use the reference variable for the arg since we need to use the `malloc` function to assign a address to `c` .

```cpp
typedef struct lnode{
    int data;
    struct lnode* next;
}lnode;


void createlistF(lnode* &c,int a[],int n)
{
    c=(lnode*)malloc(sizeof(lnode));
    c->next=NULL;
    lnode *s;
    for (int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        s=(lnode*)malloc(sizeof(lnode));
        s->data=a[i];
        s->next=c->next;
        c->next=s;
    }
}
```

I mean,why not to write like this?

```cpp
typedef struct lnode{
    int data;
    struct lnode* next;
}lnode;

lnode* createlistF(int a[],int n)
{
    lnode *c;
    c=(lnode*)malloc(sizeof(lnode));
    c->next=NULL;
    lnode *s;
    for (int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        s=(lnode*)malloc(sizeof(lnode));
        s->data=a[i];
        s->next=c->next;
        c->next=s;
    }
    return c;
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me understand this thing.Thank you!

Comment: Pick a language. Either write C++ code, or write C code. There are no C++ style references in C, only pointers. In C++ you should be using the new operator, not malloc.

Comment: `lnode* &c` or `lnode **c` are just typical out parameters in C++.  Sometimes it's necessary, but in your example, not so much. Many would probably argue in favor of a function return value of `lnode *`.

Comment: You pass in a reference because whoever is teaching you C++ is _actually_ teaching you C :(

Comment: This question is confusing: first because of what jqdonahue already highlighted; second because you ask about reference, but then *also* ask "why not" about an alternative that does not even have that argument, but returns a value. It would have made more sense if you had asked about a version that had the same argument, but not as reference.

Comment: What happens if you don't use a reference? Try it out.